# Javascript code adding something that shouldnt be there

Tags: javascript

I am creating a website and I want to style a menu that only shows up one way when displayed at certain px width. I will later change the code to do an if statement that checks if it is a touch screen. But, for now I must px width to test the code. However, my current code even though it loads correctly a certain width after I change to a higher width it still adds my label and input.
[My codepen](http://codepen.io/SousukeAlexein/pen/aNXgPg)

My javascript code.

```js
  var mediaTab = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)");

  function addmenu() {
    if (mediaTab) {
      var menu = document.querySelector("#top-lvl-menu");
      var navBar = document.querySelector("nav");
      var navToggle = document.createElement("label");
      var navInput = document.createElement("input");

      navToggle.innerHTML = "&#9776; Menu";
      navToggle.className = "menu";
      navInput.id = "menu-Toggle";
      navInput.type = "checkbox";
      navToggle.appendChild(navInput);

      navBar.insertBefore(navToggle, menu);
      navToggle.appendChild(menu);
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", addmenu, false);
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="top-lvl-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      <ul id="services-submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) window.matchMedia:

> Returns a new MediaQueryList object representing the parsed results of the specified media query string.

Therefore, it returns an object regardless of whether the window size satisfies the media query.

Fortunately the object is returns includes a 'matches' property.

Try:

```
...
if(mediaTab.matches){...}
```

EDIT: Also, this method is only supported as far back as ie10. You might want to consider just using window.innerWidth, then comparing within the if statement.

```
var mediaTab = window.innerWidth;
if(mediaTab < 1024){...}
```